# How can i read text from a window with java?

Tags: java

i'm working with java and i want to read text from a window (not java). I attach an example of a window i want to read text from.

I tried with JNA but i can not understand how to navigate the windows for read the text, here my code:

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.LRESULT;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

public class Prova_2 {

interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {        
    User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);
    int WM_SETTEXT = 0x000c;
    int WM_GETTEXT = 0x000D;

    HWND FindWindowA(String lpClassName, String lpWindowName);
    HWND FindWindowExA(HWND hwndParent, HWND hwndChildAfter, String lpClassName, String lpWindowName);
    LRESULT SendMessageA(HWND editHwnd, int wmGettext, long l, byte[] lParamStr);
    int GetClassNameA(HWND hWnd, byte[] lpString, int maxCount);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    User32 user32 = User32.INSTANCE;
    HWND notePadHwnd = user32.FindWindowA(null , "Codesys");
    HWND editHwnd = user32.FindWindowExA(notePadHwnd, null, "SysLink", null); 
    byte[] lParamStr = new byte[512];
    user32.SendMessageA(editHwnd, User32.WM_GETTEXT, 512, lParamStr);

    System.out.println("Text from external window: " + Native.toString(lParamStr));
 }
}
```

[image]

Comment: On proper OSes (Such as MacOS), this is simply not possible. One app being able to read the contents of another window is a security violation. Java is rarely the right choice for apps that fundamentally only work on a limited batch of OSes that don't do it right. If windows is all you care about, perhaps a windows-specific platform would be a better choice. In any case windows can (should) introduce a similar limitation at any time.